# least upper bound greatest lower bound theorem

Tags: analysis

I am trying to understand the following theorem:

[image: image of theorem text]

I can't understand how the author gets to the conclusion that $\alpha = \sup L$ is $\in L$

I'm ok until the "Our hypothesis about $S$ implies therefore that $L$ has a supremum in $S$, call it $\alpha$" part.

I understand until this part, but how exactly does he conclude that $\alpha$ is in $L$?

Comment: which theorem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author showed that $\alpha$ is a lower bound of $B$, hence by definition in $L$. One way to show that is suppose that $\alpha$ isn't, i.e. take $y\in B$ such that $y<\alpha$, but then since $\alpha=\sup L$ we get $z\in L$ such that $y<z<\alpha$. but $y<z$ is a contradiction.

Comment: i am not asking about the last part, my question was about the part that "if y<a then y is not upper bound of L ..... thus a $\in$ L". maybe if you could explain it more intuitively it would be better

Comment: And I have referred to that as well: if $y<\alpha$ then--being strictly smaller than the least upper bound of $L$--$y$ isn't an upper bound of $L$; therefore, $y\not\in B$. This shows that for all $y\in B$ we have $\alpha\leq y$ (the negation of $y<\alpha$), hence $\alpha$ is a lower bound for $B$, and by definition $\alpha\in L$.

Comment: y isn't an upper bound of L; therefore, y∉B - could you elaborate how you conclude that. do you refer here that L is the set of all lower bounds of B. and B is the set of some upper bounds of L?

Comment: Certainly. $L$ is the set of lower bounds of $B$, hence for all $a\in L$, $b\in B$ we have $a\leq b$. But this implies that while $B$ might not be the set of *all* upper bounds of $L$, every element of $B$ *is* an upper bound for $L$.

Answer (score 0):

"If $\gamma<\alpha$ then $\gamma$ is not an upper bound of $L$" - That's because $\alpha$ is the *least* upper bound of $L$.

"hence $\gamma\notin B$" - as we have seen before that every element of $B$ is an upper bound of $L$

"It follows that $\alpha\le x$ for all $x\in B$" - This is just the contraposition of what we just did: $\gamma<\alpha\rightarrow \gamma\notin B$ becomes $\gamma\in B\to \gamma\ge \alpha$ or after renaming of variables $x\in B\to x\ge \alpha$.

"It follows that $\alpha\in L$" - The previos sentence was just a rephrasing of "$\alpha$ is a lower bound of $B$".